# How to interrupt python script that is running a bash command?

Tags: python, linux, bash

I'm running a python script, which is running a bash command `cmd` via

```py
try:
    subprocess.run(['/bin/bash', '-ic', cmd])
except as e:
    print("Error:", e)
```

I run this python script from a bash terminal. When I press `cntrl-C` while some bash command is being executed, it seems like only the bash command is interrupted, but the python script keeps running (without capturing and printing the exception `e`. **How do I get `cntrl-C` or some other terminal command to interrupt or cause an exception in python itself?**

Comment: Did you read `subprocess.run` documentation? What parameters does it lists? Did you read module `subprocess` documentation? What other function are there? Might any be insteresting to you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true)

Comment: I would expect the exception to be fired, if the subprocess can't be created. Try tor replace `/bin/bash` by some non-existing command. I guess that you would see _Error_ then.

Comment: As for your question, you could test the exit code of your command. If it is 130, the command was aborted by control-C.

Answer (score 2):

The Python script doesn't receive the signal because it's running the shell as a subprocess.

To handle Ctrl-C in your Python script and capture the KeyboardInterrupt exception, you can use the signal module:

```
import subprocess
import signal

def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    raise KeyboardInterrupt("Ctrl-C pressed")

# Register the signal handler
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

cmd = "add_command_here"

try:
    subprocess.run(['/bin/bash', '-ic', cmd])
except Exception as e:
    print("Error:", e)
```

Comment: Does `signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)` register the `signal_handler` to fire for a signal to all subprocesses? I'm confused because if the python script doesn't receive the signal at all, then how does `signal` receive the SIGINT?

Comment: `signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)` registers the `signal_handler` to be called when the Python script itself receives a `SIGINT` signal which is the signal sent when you press Ctrl-C in the terminal where the script is running. This line of code doesn't automatically propagate the signal to subprocesses.
If you want the subprocess spawned by `subprocess.run` to also respond to Ctrl-C, you can set the `preexec_fn` argument in the `subprocess.run` call to the `os.setpgrp`. This will create a new process group for the subprocess, and Ctrl-C will be sent to the entire process group.